# Is there a simple way to time a function call in elisp?

Tags: elisp

Yes, I am aware of the emacs profiler feature.  I'm looking for something similar to the `time` keyword in bash, something like:

```
(time (myfunc))
```

which would return or print the time taken by the `myfunc` call.  Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[benchmark.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsLispBenchmark) provides `benchmark-run` and `benchmark-run-compiled` functions as well as a `benchmark` version to run interactively. The linked example:

```
C-u 512 M-x benchmark (sort (number-sequence 1 512) '<)
Elapsed time: 0.260000s (0.046000s in 6 GCs)
```

The timer used by all those functions is the `benchmark-elapse` macro, which you can also use directly if desired:

```
ELISP> (require 'benchmark)
ELISP> (benchmark-elapse
         (sit-for 2))
2.00707889
```

Answer (score 2):

I found exactly what I was looking for at http://nullprogram.com/blog/2009/05/28/

`` (defmacro measure-time (&rest body)
  "Measure and return the running time of the code block."
  (declare (indent defun))
  (let ((start (make-symbol "start")))
    `(let ((,start (float-time)))
       ,@body
       (- (float-time) ,start)))) ``

Comment: Could you explain why this is better than `benchmark-run`?

Comment: It's lighter-weight. I was looking for something super simple.

Comment: You could use `benchmark-elapse`, then. I've added it to Jon's answer.